# how to deal with nan_policy bug in Spearman test in python

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I would like to deal with nan result in Spearman test. looks like [nan_policy parameter is broken](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6654). How can I fix this issue?

```
from scipy import stats
pvalue=stats.spearmanr([10,100],[1,100])[1]
print(pvalue)
```

returns `nan`

```
pvalue=stats.spearmanr([10,100],[1,100],nan_policy='omit')[1]
print(pvalue)
```

returns `nan`

[link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115900/python-scipy-scipy-stats-spearmanr-returning-nans) related question that doesn't solve this issue.
[link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-to-check-for-nan-in-python) how to check for nan in python.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure your example demonstrates a bug in the `nan_policy` parameter which refers to *inputs* not *outputs* and there are no `nans` in your input.

You're getting `nan` because your samples are too short for meaningful statistics. Technically, you are probably right, *p* value should always be finite, so it is a bug.

That said, if I do not totally misunderstand what Spearman's rank cc is, the function does return wrong *p* values, e.g.

```
>>> stats.spearmanr(np.arange(4.),np.arange(4.))
SpearmanrResult(correlation=1.0, pvalue=0.0)
```

having four samples with the same rank order really isn't that unlikely.

Edit: The above smells to me like they are using an approximation formula for the distribution of rank cc's which doesn't work too well for small *n*. So what can you do? If your *n* is small, don't use this function (sorry, I can't be more constructive; you could compute the distribution of rank cc's by brute force and then calculate the *p*-value yourself); if your actual samples are large you're probably fine, but I would crosscheck a few examples against some other stats software.

Comment: "If *n* is small don't use this function" is good advice, although I'd be less strict about it. It is fine to use the function even with small *n* to obtain *r* but the *p*-value is meaningless. That is what the documentation has to say about p-values and sample size: *The p-values are not entirely reliable but are probably reasonable for datasets larger than **500** or so.*