# Why I get nan in spearman correlation in python

Tags: python, scipy

I am using `scipy` to calculate the correlations. My code to calculate spearman correlation is as follows.

```
from scipy import stats
sequence_1 = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
sequence_2 = [0, 0.009783728115345005, 0, 0, 0.0019759230121848587, 0.0007535430349118562, 0.0002661781514710257, 0, 0, 0.0007835762419683435]
myspearman = stats.spearmanr(sequence_1,sequence_2)
print(myspearman)
```

I get the following results from the code.

```
SpearmanrResult(correlation=nan, pvalue=nan)
```

Even though, there are some SO questions in this topic, they specifically do not answer my questions.

My questions are as follows.

- I want to somehow get a value for my correlation. In that sense, what
  is the equivalent value of `nan`?
- My other question is; is there a way to avoid this and get actual
  values in python?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: are you sure that you want the ***spearman*** correlation and not the ***pearson*** correlation? Usually, spearman correlation is performed on ranked data so that having so many ties is unlikely to occur.

Comment: @LucasRoberts I am happy to try `pearson` correlation if it does not give any nans :)

Comment: Well, Pearson correlation coefficient (that can be computed using ```pearsonr()``` from SciPy) will output ```NaN``` for the same reason if you keep using a list with no variance.

Comment: @EmJ, `pearsonr()` will return `Nan` too. However, it will return an informative message provided you are using SciPy version 1.3.X. I believe Warren put in a patch to fix the issue and provide an informative error message. That is about as much as you could hope for in this scenario as well, although you aren't getting an informative message for `spearmanr`.

Comment: @EmJ, I'd suggest you file a bug report on the scipy github repo: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues or if you prefer I can open one on your behalf and link this this post.

Comment: @LucasRoberts thanks a lot. I think that is a great suggestion.It would be great if you could link this post as I do not have a github account. :)

Comment: @EmJ sure, I'll post an issue and cross link. I'll also post an answer here because it doesn't really make sense to me that you want to use `spearmanr()` given that your data do not appear to be ranks. I agree that a more informative response from the function would be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why does `spearmanr` output a `NaN` ?

There is **no variation** in `sequence_1` so its standard deviation is equal to 0 which will result in zero division in the `spearmanr()` function, thereby returning a `NaN`.

> What is the equivalent value of `NaN` in that case?

Mathematically speaking, the Spearman correlation coefficient **is undefined** when the standard deviation in one of the two lists is equal to zero (where all instances of the random variable take the exact same value). I suggest you to study the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient)
 to better understand why if this is not straightforward!

> Is there a way to avoid this and get actual values in Python?

Since the actual value is undefined, you do get the *right* value with a `NaN`. You might however want to rely on other formulas for such issue, such as the covariance between the two variables - which, in that case, would be equal to zero.

Comment: I like the covariance suggestion. For readers of the answer, the property of covariance you are referring to is here on the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties the one listed $Cov(X,a)=0$ .

Answer (score 5):

For me (not in your case) it was because my input data had a NaN in it. Posting for those who come from a Google search, like I did.

Comment: Adding ```nan_policy='omiit'``` will ignore ```NaN```s in the input.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues here, the first is already commented in the answer by The half blood prince.

For that issue it doesn't matter which type of correlation in `scipy.stats` you choose because there is 0 variability in one of the 2 sequences you'd like to correlate.

I noted in a comment to the post that usually `spearmanr()` is used for ranks and it does not seem like you are correlating ranked data. I'm making that assessment based on non-integral values of the 2 sequences-usually ranks are non-negative integral values.

Given the second issue (as it seems) I'd recommend using `pearsonr()`. Provided your version of scipy is `1.3.X` or greater, the error message is informative and tells you exactly this issue:

```
>>> myspearman = stats.pearsonr(sequence_1,sequence_2)
/Users/rlucas/scipy-dev/scipy/scipy/stats/stats.py:3508: PearsonRConstantInputWarning: An input array is constant; the correlation coefficent is not defined.
  warnings.warn(PearsonRConstantInputWarning())
```

Also, for consistency `scipy.stats.spearmanr()` should have a similar warning thrown for `spearmanr()`. I've opened an issue in the github repo mentioning the issue and crosslinking with this SO thread. Also placing the cross link from here to the issue,

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11111

Answer (score 0):

This problem can easily be solved with the more advanced Scipy function for spearman test.

Just do as follows:

1. import the advanced function of Scipy for spearman test:

- `from scipy.stats.mstats import spearmanr`

2. Conduct the spearman test with this function:

- `spearmanr(sequence_1,sequence_2)`

3. Thus you get: `SpearmanrResult(correlation=0.0, pvalue=1.0)`

That's it, I hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

The error is majorly due to the standard deviation of the first series in zero.

Just by changing one value in your first series as below you will get the result, as now standard deviation is nonzero.

```
from scipy import stats
sequence_1 = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0]
sequence_2 = [0, 0.009783728115345005, 0, 0, 0.0019759230121848587, 0.0007535430349118562, 0.0002661781514710257, 0, 0, 0.0007835762419683435]
myspearman = stats.spearmanr(sequence_1,sequence_2)
print(myspearman)
```

output

```
SpearmanrResult(correlation=0.30949223029508643, pvalue=0.3841919479937841)
```

Comment: I don't think that the problem comes from the presence of zeros but rather from the absence of variance in one of the two lists!